# Accessing UITabBarController from UIVIewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitabbar

I am developing an application based on UITabbar and the view hierarchy as follows.

UITabBarController ----> UINavigationController ----> UIViewController

I need to access the UITabBarController from the UIIVewController . But following properties always returns nil.

self.tabBarController and self.navigationController.tabBarController

Is there a way to access the Tabbarcontroller directly from a child viewController without using the AppDelegate ?

```
@implementation HomeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.title = @"Home";
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Home";

        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarHome"];

        UITabBarController *tab = self.tabBarController;
         UITabBarController *tab1 = self.navigationController.tabBarController;
        UITabBarController *tab2 = self.navigationController.presentingViewController;



    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: it's possible to just use `self.tabBarController` from any `UIViewController` that is embedded in the `UITabBarController`, check @Rashad's answer below

Comment: @Rashad's answer is correct , please check

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With the hierachy that you are using:

[image]

I can acces without problem the `UITabBarController` from the `ViewController` with:

> self.tabBarController

Move your Custom initialization to `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`

Then for shure you can access `TabBarController` with `self.tabBarController`

Another way to arrive to your TabBarController is:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController;
```

But it is totally unnecessary in your case.

**EDIT:**

If you are working with Xib, then you has been created a TabBarController programmatically in your AppDelegate. I'm sure you have something like:

> self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

Then you can call it in your ViewController:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = appDelegate.tabBarController;
```

Comment: You are right moving in to viewDidLoad helped. Any particular reason why we can't access it during the initialization ?

Comment: This doesn't work on Xcode 7 beta 6. can anyone else confirm this works?

Comment: This does not work on xCode 9. Something this basic is screwed up :(

Answer (score 6):

You are doing it wrong.

I've an app same as yours. I can access tabbar from `viewDidLoad`.

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)