# run check on entering another tab on ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I recently started programming for iOS. In my program I have two tabs on a Tab Bar Controller. Every time the user wants to enter the second tab I need to check if an array called players has enough entries. I tried it with a simple if-statement in the `viewDidLoad` function. But I found out, that this function is only called on the first time the tab was entered. So I wanted to ask how to do it?

Now my second question is: How can I bring back the first tab if there are not enough player entries after showing an `UIAlertView`?

thanks for your response.

So I moved my code into the `viewDidLoad` function. It gets called every time I open the tab. But the other part with switching back to the first tab does not work properly:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   if([[self players] count] < 2)
   {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please add at least two players!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

      [alert show];

      UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.presentingViewController;
      [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

}

Comment: To see how to access the tab bar controler from within the presented view controller see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807240/accessing-uitabbarcontroller-from-uiviewcontroller

Comment: thanks this post is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run something every time a UIViewController appears, use [`viewWillAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear%3a) or [`viewDidAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear%3a), depending on when you want to check.

To programmatically go back from one view controller in the UITabBarController to another one, set the UITabBarController's [`selectedViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController) or [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedIndex) properties by accessing it from the child view controller by using `self.tabBarController`.

Alternatively, use UITabBarControllerDelegate's [tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController%3ashouldSelectViewController%3a) method to decide whether or not the second view should be selected (and show an alert if it shouldn't).